# how can I add function to my success button?

Tags: jquery

I want to add function to my success button, or some similar to action: in my modal with bootstrap how can I do it?

```
$('#add_item').on('click',function(){
     $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static', 
        keyboard: false,
     });
});
```

Comment: What function do you want to add?

Comment: i want to add whatever function , $.ajax({}) or other

Answer (score 0):

**Try one these bad boys:**

```
 $('#add_item').on('click',function(){
       $('#myModal').modal({
         backdrop: 'static', 
         keyboard: false,
         $(this).hide();               // add hide function inside of modal
         $('#add_item').hover(function() {  // add hover event handler && function inside of modal
           $(this).text('new text');
         });
       });
       $('.class').hide();              // add hide function outside of modal
       $('.class').hover(function(){    // add hover event handler && function outside of modal
        $('#add_item'). 
      }); 
 });
```